# Adding Woocommerce category meta value to a sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type, sidebar

I have added a custom post type dropdown to my product categories (see below):

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_type'        => 'banner',
);
$stickers = get_posts( $args ); 

echo '<label for="product-banner">Productbanner</label>';
echo '<select name="product-banner" class="product-banner">';
echo '<option value="">Geen banner</option>';
foreach($stickers as $sticker){
    echo '<option value="'.$sticker->ID.'">'.get_the_title($sticker->ID).'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

And to save it:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['product-banner'] ) ) {

    $new_meta_value = $_POST['product-banner'];
    $meta_key = 'product-banner';

    update_term_meta( $term_id, $meta_key, $new_meta_value );

}
```

I am showing the sidebar on category pages, and i would like to show the featured image of my selected custom post type dropdown item in there as well.

Is there an easy solution to do this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT :

```
$tax_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
if (get_term_meta($tax_id, 'product-banner', true)) {
    $banner_id = get_term_meta($tax_id, 'product-banner', true);
    //echo $banner_id;
    $banner_post = get_post($banner_id);
    $banner_img = get_post_thumbnail_id($banner_post);
    echo '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_image_url( $banner_img, 'full' ).'"style="margin-bottom:-17px;border:1px solid #e8e8e8;" />';
    //echo get_queried_object()->term_id;  
}
```

Comment: After some fiddling i got it working ;) (See edit)